# Как отсортировать двумерный массив по столбцу?

Tags: c++, алгоритм, сортировка

Есть массив string M[21][6]. 
[image: Массив]
Нужно отсортировать его по последнему столбцу с сохранением привязки к строке.
Второй день пытаюсь что-то делать, ничего не получается.
Желательно решение иметь максимально простое, без использования каких-либо сложных функций.

Comment: std::sort https://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort

Comment: Я пыталась делать так, но у меня не получилось. Сейчас еще посижу, постараюсь. Спасибо

Answer (score 2):

Как-то так.

Такое решение не тянет на "максимально простое", зато кода немного.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <array>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::array<std::string, 3>> arr // Тут вместо 3 у вас будет 6.
    {
        {"a", "b", "12"},
        {"e", "f", "28"},
        {"c", "d", "14"},
        {"foo", "bar", "6"},
        {"hello", "world", "5"},
    };

    // Печатаем
    for (const auto &x : arr)
    {
        for (const auto &y : x)
            std::cout << std::setw(10) << y;
        std::cout << '\n';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';

    // Сортируем
    std::sort(arr.begin(), arr.end(), [](const auto &a, const auto &b)
    {
        int column = a.size()-1;// Номер столбца = последний
        const auto &a_str = a[column];
        const auto &b_str = b[column];
        if (auto x = a_str.size() - b_str.size())
            return x > 0;
        return a_str < b_str;
    });

    // Снова печатаем
    for (const auto &x : arr)
    {
        for (const auto &y : x)
            std::cout << std::setw(10) << y;
        std::cout << '\n';
    }
}
```

<kbd>[Демо](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7a3fcda7d6cfa429)</kbd>

Comment: Спасибо большое. Не уверена, что смогу защитить это решение, но буду разбираться, раз других вариантов нет

Comment: @AmeliaParker не нужно защищать чужой код , пишите свой. Там все очевидно. Так вы никогда сами не напишите ничего полезного

Answer (score 1):

@HolyBlackCat в своем ответе уже дал направление как можно реализовать произвольную сортировку изпользуя методы стандартной библиотеки. Рекомендую рассмотреть подробнее как работает `sort`, т.к. «свою» сортировку Вам нужно будет писать только при обучении чтобы понять как что работает и «набить» руку. На практике для сортировки практически всегда нужно использовать стандартные методы: во-первых, это быстрее, во-вторых, так меньше шансов допустить ошибку.

Я в своем ответе напишу как применить алгоритм сортировки к двумерному массиву.

Смотрите, главное это алгоритм. То, как его применить к двумерному массив/многомерному массиву/вектору/списку это детали реализации. Т.ч. если хотите сами реализовать сортировку начать нужно с выбора алгоритма сортировки, [их много](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC_%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B8).

Допустим, выбрали самый простой вариант: [сортировка вставками](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8). Реализуем его для простого случая: одномерного массива. Получится что-то вроде:

```
int n = 3;
string m[] = {
    "17463",
    "19436",
    "16789"
};

for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
    for(int j=i+1; j<n; j++) {
        if(m[i]>m[j]) {               //сравнение
            string tmp = m[i];        //перестановка
            m[i] = m[j];
            m[j] = tmp;
        }
    }
}
```

Запустите и убедитесь, что алгоритм работает. Если надо, просмотрите как изменяется массив на каждом шаге, чтобы было понятно как работает алгоритм.

Что характерно, основной принцип алгоритма останется таким же для любого вида входных данных. Изменятся только технические моменты: по другому будут сравниваться элементы, по другому они будут переставляться. Эти моменты отмечены в коде выше комментариями. Для ясности вынесем их в отдельные функции:

```
bool more(string a[], int i, int j) {
    return a[i] > a[j];
}

void swap(string a[], int i, int j) {
    string tmp = a[i];        
    a[i] = a[j];
    a[j] = tmp;
}

...
for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
     for(int j=i+1; j<n; j++) {
          if(more(m, i, j)) {               //сравнение
               swap(m, i, j);
          }
     }
}
...
```

Теперь, для того чтобы перейти к случаю когда `m` — двумерный массив потребуется только переписать эти два метода.

Метод сравнения переписывается легко, просто сравниваем последние элементы:

```
bool more(string a[][6], int i, int j) {
    return a[i][5] > a[j][5];
}
```

С перестановкой сложнее т.к. для копирования строк массива нужно будет пройти по всем столбцам массива. Вот заготовка, допишите циклы сами:

```
void swap(string a[][6], int i, int j) {
    //временная переменная для хранения строки
    string tmp[6];
    for(int x=0; x<6; x++) {
        //копируем a[i] в tmp
    }
    //a[i] = a[j];
    //a[j] = tmp;
}
```

После этого алгоритм должен работать без существенных изменений:

```
int n = 3;
string m[][6] = {
    {"", "", "Evansville", "", "", "17463"},
    {"", "", "Biloxi", "", "", "19436"},
    {"", "", "London", "", "", "16789"}
};

for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
    for(int j=i+1; j<n; j++) {
        if(more(m, i, j)) {               
            swap(m, i, j);
        }
    }
}
```

Функции потом можно будет перенести обратно в код, главное чтобы Вы понимали идею алгоритма. Код в любом случае будет достаточно прост.

Этот подход можно применить к любому алгоритму сортировки, главное — отметить какие технические особенности изменятся при переходе от одномерного к двумерному массиву.